# Material won't apply to mesh

Tags: materials

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? I'm attaching the file. Why are my materials not assigning to the eye? I have one for the inner eye mesh called "eyeball" and one for the outer eye mesh called "outereye".

Also, when you open the file, you will see a logo on the character's body. I followed the tutorial, which told me to use an empty, but the result is supposed to be one logo on his chest. As you can see, the logo is repeating all over his body.

EDIT: Actually I see the logo in the center now when I render. Is it possible to see it in center without having to render?

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B85i1BKJ9r96Z0NCM3RoNFVpZzQ

Thanks

Comment: see this link: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

Comment: Already did that and it doesn't work. Or maybe it is assigning it but there's something wrong with the material itself? It looks like an eyeball on the preview and just like in the tutorial but I'm not seeing it on the mesh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The material is assigned to the faces of the eyes, but the coordinates for the texture are wrong.

Set them to UV...[image]

The other eye is a mess too... it needs to be UV unwrapped.

[image]

Comment: when I did this for the first time, I didn't have to do that. The book says to use "Generated mapping". I don't know if that was because the eyes were in different layers and I then moved them to the same layer as the  rest of the body? (Had to, to move the head with them) When I do what you do, the texture looks bad in the preview, but seemed to render fine. Why? I also can't see it on the model until I render. As for the other eye, why do I get that diagonal line for UVs? When I press E I don't get anything else.

Comment: The UV unwrapping for both eyes is different.

Comment: How do I fix the UVs? All I've done so far in this book apart from creating seams for the head is unwrap using E and it's worked.

Comment: Look for tutorials on UV unwrapping. If you have further questions please ask them in separate posts.

Comment: I fixed it. Someone helped me in a different forum. I got a good idea about the UVs now. But the material preview still looks bad, before all this it looked just like an eyeball. And I can't see the material on the model either unless I render, where it does look perfect. What's causing this?

Comment: New questions please ask them in a different post. This is not a forum but a question and answer site. One question per post. Clean and simple.  Why? Think of someone looking for an answer to something like "why do I get a diagonal line for UVs?" or "I can't see the material on the model either unless I render"... How is this person going to know that the information is found by searching for "Material won't apply to mesh"?

Comment: I understand that, but it's much easier to answer questions sometimes by following what's been happening to this point. Making a new question means I gotta post all the info again, the file, etc. It's all related to my original problem. It's not clear how related a question has to be to post in the same thread or as a different question. With Google, which everyone uses, people can't find more than just thread titles.